# Grouping duplicate objects into an array of values

Tags: python, json

Need to group the set of objects with duplicate value 
**Input**

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "check_no": "1.4",
      "security": "IAM"
    },
    {
      "check_no": "1.3",
      "security": "SLM"
    },
    {
      "check_no": "1.4",
      "security": "EKM"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here the check_no inside the array has 1.4, 1.3, 1.4. I need to group them into an array with an additional key as shown below 
**Output**

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "check_no": "1.4",
      "values": [
        {
          "security": "IAM"
        },
        {
          "security": "EKM"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "check_no": "1.3",
      "values": [
        {
          "security": "SLM"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: There is someone who understood my question & gave an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to collect the `"security": "EKM"` per `"check_no"`, for that a `defaultdict` is very suitable, then rebuild the result

```
from collections import defaultdict

grouped_check_no = defaultdict(list)
for error in v['errors']:
    grouped_check_no[error['check_no']].append({"security": error['security']})

result = {'errors': [{"check_no": k, "values": v} for k, v in grouped_check_no.items()]}
```

```
grouped_check_no is
{'1.4': [{'security': 'IAM'}, {'security': 'EKM'}], '1.3': [{'security': 'SLM'}]}
```